# Network configuration when debugging windows mobile with active sync?

Tags: windows, debugging, networking, windows-mobile, gprs

I'm trying to debug a windows mobile app. The app is starting and is debugging all right, but it always seem to use the usb connection to the computer as it's internet connection. I need the mobile device to use it's GPRS connection when debugging.
Is it possible and how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Windows Mobile Device Center.

- Connect without setting up your device
- Mobile Device Settings
- Connection Settings
- Select Allow data connection on device when connected to PC