# wifi:become unavailable after turn on

Tags: visual-studio, networking, windows-mobile, activesync, wifi

After connect `Symbol Motorola MC75` to ActiveSync, Then I turn on WiFi on device but it automatically become `unavailable`..

can I know why this happen?

The condition is, I'm on debugging the mobile application project `Window Mobile SDK 6 Device` at `Symbol Motorola MC75` through `ActiveSync`,

I want to test WiFi connection... When I turn Off Wifi at the device it's has no problem but when I tried to turn On the device it's automatically become Unavailable. The project is using c# language and running on VS2005.

I also check at tab `Find WLANS` but get error about `Scan Error Adapter Unavailable`.

My laptop already connect to wireless or internet...

Comment: Can you describe in more detail what you mean with unavailable? Does this relate so programming at all? You might also want to read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints .

Comment: @yuri sorry there are no link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After check `ActiveSync`, I see that I must tick Allow wireless connection on device when connected to desktop. The the WiFi will become show Network Card that mean it's have connection with internet... However thanks for all help!!!

Answer (score 2):

I've reproduced the behaivor you mention. Not being 100% sure about what causes it, but I'll believe the network communication gets done via ActiveSync, so it disables the WIFI adapter.

I'm guessing your setup it's the following.

PC -> Cradle -> Device

So you can deploy your code and test it disconnected from the development pc. Or you could try  this [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7980764/network-configuration-when-debugging-windows-mobile-with-active-sync/)

Comment: Bingo. This is exactly what happens. The OS is shutting down the network adapters when the cradle is detected and all network traffic is routed through RNDIS.  The "solution" is to use network debugging and forego ActiveSync and the cradle altogether.